# Why do i get two outputs?

Tags: c++

I've been writing this code for my biology class. The idea is the user inputs teh DNA and the code outputs the respective mRNA and aminoacid sequence of it.It worked pretty much without any error but then i noticed it sometimes gives two outputs instead of one. (For example "Ile Met " instead of "Met") Also i know my code is a mess so can you please help by that too, which parts and how should i change?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sdna;
    cout << "Enter codogener strang: ";
    cin >> sdna;
    int n = sdna.size();
    char dna[100];
    char mrna[100];
    strcpy_s(dna, sdna.c_str());
    cout << "DNA: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << dna[i];
        if (i % 3 == 2)
            cout << " ";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (dna[i] == 'A')
            mrna[i] = 'U';
        else if (dna[i] == 'T')
            mrna[i] = 'A';
        else if (dna[i] == 'G')
            mrna[i] = 'C';
        else if (dna[i] == 'C')
            mrna[i] = 'G';
    }
    cout << "\nmRNA: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << mrna[i];
        if (i % 3 == 2)
            cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A'))
            cout << "Ile ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'G'))
            cout << "Met ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Thr ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C'))
            cout << "Asn ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'G' || 'A'))
            cout << "Lys ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C'))
            cout << "Ser ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'G' || 'A'))
            cout << "Arg ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Val ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Ala ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C'))
            cout << "Asp ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Glu ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Gly ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C'))
            cout << "Phe ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Leu ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Ser ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'A' || 'G')) {
            cout << "Stopp ";
            return 0;
        }
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C'))
            cout << "Tyr ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'A')) {
            cout << "Stopp ";
            return 0;
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C'))
            cout << "Cys ";
        }
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'G'))
            cout << "Trp ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'U') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Leu ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Pro ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C'))
            cout << "His ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'A') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Gln ";
        if ((mrna[k * 3] == 'C') && (mrna[k * 3 + 1] == 'G') && (mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A' || 'G'))
            cout << "Arg ";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the code supposed to do? Why is `Ile Met` wrong? what is the input that causes this output? What is the expected output? please show a [mre]. `|| 'C' || 'A'` will always be true, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: the first two conditions are not exclusive. If the second condition is `true` then the first is `true` too. Probably you want to make them mutually exclusive, then use `if / else if` instead of many `if`s. Though also then the second condition cannot be `true` without the first being `true` as well

Comment: By seeing all those repetitions in your code I have the strung impression that your code could be rewritten 3-4 times less lines.

Comment: you should explain what the code does. We only see your code and you say it doesnt do what you want, but we don't know what you want. Include input, output and expected output (I think several examples are needed to understand the logic)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number what this code is *supposed* to do should be obvious to anyone who studied biology (and Keratius tried to also explain it) - convert triplets of DNA or RNA bases into the matching amino acid. More than one triplets can match the same amino acid, but of course for every triplet there is just one amino acid; Outputting both Ile and Met at the same time for one input triplet is the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is `(mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A')`.
You probably thought that this checks whether `mrna[k * 3 + 2]` is equal to either `U`, `C` or `A`. But that's not what it does... The `||` ("or") operators combines three conditions - one of them is `mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U'`, as you expected, but the other two are `'C'` and `'A'`. The C/C++ language treats these character constants as unconditionally true (because they are numbers not equal zero), so the entire expression is unconditionally true.

The correct code would be `(mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'C' || mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'A')`.

You can save `mrna[k * 3 + 2`] in a variable with a shorter name to make these expressions shorter, and also faster (however, modern optimizers will do this optimization for you automatically, even if you don't do it explicitly).

Answer (score 4):

I am suspicious of all of your conditions of the form `mrna[k * 3 + 2] == 'U' || 'C' || 'A'`. That doesn't check `mrna[k * 3 + 2]` against any of the three letters, it is unconditionally `true`.

I would also advise against using `char [100]`. You are already reading into a `std::string`, that also has `operator[]`, and it also has `operator==`.

You are also (potentially) indexing past the end of your data. Your loop condition is `k < n`, where n is the "length" of `mrna`, but you index `mrna[k * 3]`. Either change the condition, or change how you index.

But what I would most suggest is to replace the long string of `if`s with a `std::map`, which you can populate for each triple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

void print_triple(const std::string & s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << s[i];
        if (i % 3 == 2)
            std::cout << " ";
    }
}

static std::map<std::string, std::string> mrna_lookup
{
    { "AUU", "Ile " },
    { "AUC", "Ile " },
    { "AUA", "Ile " },
    { "AUG", "Met " },
    // etc
};

int main()
{
    std::string dna;
    std::cout << "Enter codogener strang: ";
    std::cin >> dna;

    std::cout << "DNA: ";
    print_triple(dna);

    std::string mrna;
    for (char c : dna)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'A': mrna.push_back('U'); break;
            case 'T': mrna.push_back('A'); break;
            case 'G': mrna.push_back('C'); break;
            case 'C': mrna.push_back('G'); break;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nmRNA: ";
    print_triple(mrna);

    cout << "\n";

    std::string_view mrna_view = mrna; // view so .substr doesn't copy
    
    for (int k = 0; k+2 < mrna.size(); k += 3)
    {
        auto it = mrna_lookup.find(mrna_view.substr(k, 3));
        if (it != mrna_lookup.end())
        {
            std::cout << it->second;
            if (it->second == "Stopp ")
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```